# Remix IDE not allowing me to choose Injected Provider-Meta

Tags: remix

I am unable to switch environment from Remix London to Injected Provider-Metamask for testing out my smartcontract, currently my metamask is on Rinkeby Test network.

Comment: Issue Solved , try Switch to a different browser with MetaMask and reconnect
OR
Ensure MetaMask is unlocked, refresh RemixIDE, and reconnect

Answer (score 2):

Hey is it showing any error?
Or maybe you can try out another network as well.
Also, share the screenshot for the same.

Comment: My contract compiled successfully and I also checked with other networks too, but remix not switching to Injected Provider.

Comment: What error is it showing.
There is nothing to do with the compilation and all.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following:

1. Switch to a different browser with MetaMask and reconnect

   OR
2. Ensure MetaMask is unlocked, refresh RemixIDE, and reconnect

Comment: Thank you, I switched the browser and try to reconnect , boom it worked.

Comment: always trust in reload button :3

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, however, refreshing the page after unlocking metamask solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try these ways:

1. Switch to a different browser with MetaMask and reconnect.
2. Ensure MetaMask is unlocked, refresh RemixIDE, and reconnect.
3. last,try removing other wallets from extensions(like safePal wallet, math Wallet, trustWallet, etc) which might be conflicting with the Metamask.